# iphone: Paint/Draw with All touches?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, paint, uitouch

How can I paint with with 4 fingers simultaneously. I need UI to interact and respond to all touches.

I have seen most of the Apps like GLPaint & many more painting apps which only respond to 1 touch.

Anyone have idea how can I paint with all touches ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that looks for panning (dragging) gestures.The user must be pressing one or more fingers on a view while they pan it.
```

Use :

```
multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

Comment: Any samples available ? Like GLPaint Apple sample

Comment: In this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238149/ios-advancing-an-animation-in-realtime-while-panning-with-uipangesturerecognize, it's mentioned this sample code :http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435